# I inadvertantly prepared and filed an 1120S return that should have been an SMLLC filing

Tags: taxes

I don't know what to do with this. The election should not have been made for many reasons. So we filed a 2020 1120S return (initial and final return checked). Now I'm not sure what I need to do to fix this. Do I amend her 1040 with the SMLLC or, is there some election I can make to make this go away? She is right as rain for 2021.

Comment: Have you filed form 2553?

Comment: the client filed it in 2019 for 2020 but it was never accepted and this election should never have been made. Too many reasons why it did not benefit her.

Comment: You're a CPA? A tax preparer?

Comment: I'm an EA - in 26 years, I've never done this. My client took it upon herself to file 2553 without telling me. My guess is she never mailed it. But the issue is I am thinking I just amend the 2020 1040. She had already paid the tax

Comment: You should probably talk to your E&O provider before you do anything. You're a professional, you have duty of care to your client and a liability for mistakes. It was your responsibility to confirm whether form 2553 was or wasn't filed, and provide adequate advice to your client. Seeking help on this forum would not bode well with you if your E&O provider (or your client) finds out...